# Where is the error in the setting up of this Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I followed the instruction to setting up Zend Framework on Mac OSX and I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Application) could not be initialized.' in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
( ! ) Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Application) could not be initialized. in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
```

I followed a couple of similar posts:

[ZF2: Module could not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265447/zf2-module-could-not-be-initialized)

[Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411743/uncaught-exception-zend-modulemanager-exception-runtimeexception-with-message)

And they do not seem to speak to my issue specifically.

Here is my file structure:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/kbase $ tree -d .                                                                                                          [ruby-2.2.1]
.
├── config
│   └── autoload
├── data
│   └── cache
├── module
│   ├── Application
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── Controller
│   │   ├── test
│   │   │   └── Controller
│   │   └── view
│   │       ├── application
│   │       │   └── index
│   │       ├── error
│   │       └── layout
│   └── Article
│       ├── config
│       ├── src
│       │   └── Article
│       │       ├── Controller
│       │       ├── Form
│       │       └── Model
│       └── views
│           └── article
│               └── article
├── public
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
│   └── js
└── vendor
    ├── bin
    ├── composer
```

kbase/module/Article/Module.php:

```
<?php
namespace Article;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                 __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }
 }
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "cs-check": "phpcs",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@development-enable"
        ],
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    },
    "autoload": {
     "psr-0": { "Article": "module/Article/src/" }
    }
}
```

kbase/config/modules.config.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Article'
];
```

kbase/module/Article/autoload.classmap.php:

```
<?php

return array();
```

This is the version of php that I have:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/kbase $ php -v                                                                                                                                                                            [ruby-2.2.5]
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 23:03:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that either there is a corrupted files or your php version is less than 5.5 version. Recent Zf2 version works on php5
5+. If your php version is good then please try again with below mentioned link.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Let me know if you are still facing issues.

Comment: I will let you know. Thank you for responding.

Comment: it looks like you pointed me in the direction of using my local server with MAMP as opposed to Zend Server. I will mark your answer as correct and keep moving forward doing it this way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am glad that I helped you here :).